# Preview not paused when picture taken

Tags: android, camera, preview

I have a camera application that I could do with some help with. In my Camera Fragment I call the method takePicture, which I is meant to pause the preview (according to [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)).

On my old HTC One X this was true, but having just upgraded to an HTC One mini2 the preview no longer pauses.

Is there a logical reason for this? Any suggested changes to my code?

I am calling takePicture with the following code:

```
if (myCamera != null) {

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    PhotoHandler myphotohandler = new PhotoHandler(fm, mycontext, getView(), Photo_Type, photonumber, getDir(Project_Name), lmanager, projecttag);

    ShutterCallback shutter = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            button_takephoto = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_takephoto);
            button_takephoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.shutter_closed);
            }
        };

        myCamera.takePicture(shutter, null, null, myphotohandler);
```

And my PhotoHandler class implements the PictureCallback.

Any suggestions or similar experiences would be appreciated.

Comment: Thrilled to receive the tumbleweed award for this post, but has anyone else dealt with a camera that does not pause the preview when a picture is taken?

Comment: A little late to the party, but yes. On my HTC One I can take a first picture and the preview pauses correctly. Then if the user discards the picture, I resume the preview, and when he takes a second picture the preview doesn't pause. Have you found a good workaround by any chance?

Comment: @MartinDevillers Hi, thanks for your comment. I did find a work around that produces a paused preview after the picture is taken. I'll post it now as an answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is to manually stop the preview in a Camera.ShutterCallback. Originally, I had only a Camera.PictureCallback handling my apps response to a picture being taken.

```
        if (myCamera != null) {

            PhotoHandler myphotohandler = new PhotoHandler();

            ShutterCallback shutter = new ShutterCallback() {
                public void onShutter() {
                    myCamera.stopPreview();
                }
            };

            myCamera.takePicture(shutter, null, null, myphotohandler);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't cause any odd behavior on any other devices? I was afraid it would, given that the preview is supposed to have already been stopped.

Comment: @MartinDevillers I've since identified this solution as the cause of an occasional bug. I think that on rare occasions (about 1 in 10 for my device) the shutter callback is completing before the jpeg callback is starting. Stopping the preview within the shutter callback then prevents the jpeg callback from happening. So I am once again without a solution to the HTC One X's refusal to stop the preview when takePicture is called.